# scala regex match

Tags: regex, scala

all - scala noob question

i am trying to match regex to the first line of a file, have issue with AVRO files: they start with `"Obj(ctl-a)(ctl-f)(ctl-v)avro.schema"`

i am using `"^Obj#010616avro.schema".r.unanchored` - doesn't work

any input appreciated, thnx v much for your time on this, mr

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i made the problem simpler, thanks for coming back, mr

Comment: What are you trying to match here, the name of the file or the first line in the file? What does `010616avro` mean? And what exactly is `Obj(ctl-a)(ctl-f)(ctl-v)avro.schema` Is that literally the name of the file or literally the first line in a file? Can you update the question with example strings that you want to match, and what the expected outcome should be?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what `#010616` is but the following regex should work:

```scala
"""^Obj\cA\cF\cVavro.schema""".r.unanchored
```

Comment: interesting - thanks for coming back on this

Comment: @MarkRostron do you remember whether it has worked?